# Why does the feedback resistor change?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

I'm looking at a reference design from TI : [18-Bit, 1MSPS Data Acquisition Block (DAQ) Optimized for Lowest Distortion and Noise](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau515/slau515.pdf)

On page 19, you'll find the following image.

[image]

It describes the circuit as having dual feedback, one for DC and one for HF, and gives te equivalent circuit for each type.

[image]

[image]

**Why does the feedback resistor (Rf) look like a short at DC and look like an open at AC ?**

Answer (score 1):

There is an outer loop provided by Rf and an inner loop provided by the local integrator capacitor Cf. At low frequencies Cf has effectively a high impedance and the outer loop dominates. This can be approximated by an open Cf and zero value Rf (since Rf impedance would be much lower than OpAmp input impedance).

While at high frequencies CF has lower impedance than Rf path and the inner loop dominates. This can be approximated as shorted Cf and open Rf.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really clever, and I never would have thought of it - but consider the role of the feedback capacitor on the OPA333. For a DC value at the output of the THS4281, the feedback resistor does change the time constant of Cf, but it has no other direct bearing on what that voltage will be - so, for a DC value, it may as well be a short.

Higher frequency operation took me a second to figure out, but as the frequency increases, the reactance of the feedback capacitor simply becomes so low that it is nearly inconsequential compared to Rf. Thus, OPA333 gets to be a unity gain buffer, and the miniscule currents across Rf won't significantly change the voltage on either side of it - meaning little to no change in the THS4281.